# How could I run python script on aws EC2 instance(ubuntu)?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, user-data

I have an ec2 instance"abc1"(ubuntu) and I create image from abc1.
Then,I launch a new instance "abc2" from abc1 image.
I want abc2 to run the script when it will be launched.
So,I write the text in userdata:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/env/xxx/bin/
source activate
python3.6 ~/env/xxx/source/test.py
```

I manually use these commands,it's valid.However,it doesn't work when using userdata automatically.
Does anyone know how to adjust my settings?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you are ssh'ing into the ec2 instance as a different user than the instance is running it at, so the HOME directory (~) is not the same when run manually vs run with cloudinit.

Try writing the script using absolute paths, not relative paths.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I have tried to write the script using absolute path(/home/ubuntu/env/xxx/bin/),but it shows /root/env/xxx/bin/
"/home/ubuntu" is exchanged to "/root/" that means I only can excute the program under the root.